# Python - Sikuli - ConfigParser.NoSectionError

Tags: python, sikuli, configparser

This is my code:

```
import ConfigParser
configuration = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
configuration.read('timesheetconfig.ini')
username = configuration.get('internal','username')
password = configuration.get('internal','password')
url  = configuration.get('internal','url')
browser = configuration.get('internal','browser')
```

I've also tried replacing:
    configuration.read('C:\SikuliConfig\timesheetconfig.ini')

This is the timesheetconfig.ini

```
[internal]
username = username
password = password
url = https://www.sometimesheeturl/login.html
browser = chrome
```

Do you know why I'm getting???

```
[error] script [ ScriptName ] stopped with error in line 4
[error] ConfigParser.NoSectionError ( No section: 'internal' )
```

Comment: I have just tried running this code and it works. The reasons for your error could be a typo in the config filename or not providing the correct path to it

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the configuration.read cannot open the file in the same folder. I tested the same code in Python with Cygwin and it works fine, so it is related to Sikuli.

I solved this issue by adding after import ConfigParser:

```
import ConfigParser
# get the directory containing your running .sikuli
myPath = os.path.dirname(getBundlePath())
if not myPath in sys.path: sys.path.append(myPath)
```

Then

```
config.read('%s\config.ini' % myPath)
```

Source search in Sikuli docs for ["Another example: Importing from the same directory"](http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html)